# ¿Porqué no me muestra nada el output? ¿Qué hago mal?

Tags: java

hice este sencillo app y la verdad que no encuentro la razón de porque no veo nada en el output. Simplemente no lo veo.

La app consiste de 3 clases, Productos, Carrito y Main.
La idea es agregar productos a un carrito y luego comparar los precios de ellos, listar los productos que están en carrito y ademas mostrar cual es el producto más caro y cual el más barato usando un compareTo.
Puede que existan otros métodos pero lo necesitaba hacer usando la interface Comparable. ¿Cuál es mi error?

MAIN:

```
 package comparaprecios2;

 public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         // char indica tipo de producto, B-bebible, H-higiene, C-comestible
         Productos producto1 = new Productos("Agua S/Gas", 1.5, 30, 'B'); 
         Productos producto2 = new Productos("Agua C/Gas", 1.5, 40, 'B');
         Productos producto3 = new Productos("Shampoo", 500, 16, 'H');
         Productos producto4 = new Productos("Bananas", 64, 'C');

         Carrito carrito = new Carrito();

         carrito.setProducto(producto1);
         carrito.setProducto(producto2);
         carrito.setProducto(producto3);
         carrito.setProducto(producto4);

         carrito.toString();
     }
      }
```

PRODUCTOS:

```
 package comparaprecios2;


 public class Productos implements Comparable {

     private double precio;
     private double tamanio;
     private char tipo;
     private String nombre;

     public Productos(String nombre, double tamanio, double precio, char tipo)
     {
         this.nombre = nombre;
         this.tamanio = tamanio;
         this.precio = precio;
         this.tipo = tipo;
     }

     public Productos(String nombre, double precio, char tipo)
     {
         this.nombre = nombre;
         this.precio = precio;
         this.tipo = tipo;
     }

     @Override
     public int compareTo(Object obj)
     {
         Productos prodTemp = (Productos) obj;

         if(prodTemp.precio < this.precio)
         {
             return -1;
         }

         if(prodTemp.precio > this.precio)
         {
             return 1;
         }

         return 0;
     }

     public String dameNombre()
     {
         return this.nombre;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString(){

         switch(tipo){
             default:
                 return "Nombre: " + nombre + " /// " + "Precio: $" + precio;
             case 'C':
                 return "Nombre: " + nombre + " /// " + "Precio: $" + precio + 
                        " /// " + "Unidad de venta: kilo";
            case 'B':
                 return "Nombre: " + nombre + " /// " + "Litros: " + tamanio + 
                        "L /// " + "Precio: $" + precio;
             case 'H':
                 return "Nombre: " + nombre + " /// " + "Contenido: " + tamanio  
                        "ml /// " + "Precio: $" + precio;         }
     }

 }
```

CARRITO:

```
 package comparaprecios2;

 import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.Collections; import
 java.util.List;


 public class Carrito {

     private static List<Productos> listaDeProductos;


     public Carrito(){

         listaDeProductos = new ArrayList();

     }

     public void setProducto(Productos x){

         listaDeProductos.add(x);

     }

     @Override
     public String toString(){

         for (int i = 0; i < listaDeProductos.size(); i++)
         {
             listaDeProductos.get(i).toString();
         }

         Collections.sort(listaDeProductos);
         return "=============================" + "\nProducto más caro: " 
                + listaDeProductos.get(listaDeProductos.size()-1).dameNombre() 
                + "\nProducto más barato: " + listaDeProductos.get(0).dameNombre();

     }
      }
```

Comment: Estas seguro que no sale nada en la consola? o se abre y se cierra?

Comment: Nada, solamente sale Run: (VACIO) BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds). Osea Nada..

Comment: ah para.. pero en ningun lado estas mandando nada a la consola.. solo estas generando los strings :)

Comment: Me ocurrió lo mismo utilizando Net Beans 19.Con ides mas viejos se imprimía en consola si estaba sobreescrito el toString y si no lo estaba la referencia al objeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estas mostrando nada en consola. Tendrías que hacer algo como `System.out.println(carrito.toString());` al final del main (que mostraría lo que devuelve el método, osea cual es el mayor y cual el menor).

Y si querés que muestre la lista, tenés que hacer lo mismo con `listaDeProductos.get(i).toString();` que está dentro del ciclo en el método `Carrito.toString();`.

(En Java no se muestra en consola lo que devuelve un método cuando no se lo asigna a ninguna variable)